# DependencyProperty getter/setter not being called

Tags: wpf, grid, dependency-properties

I am trying to create a Custom control derived from a standard Grid. 
I added a ObservableCollection as a DependencyProperty of the Custom control. However, the get/set of it is never reached. Can I have some guidelines in creating a DependencyProperty that works correctly with and ObservableCollection?

```
public class MyGrid : Grid
{
    public ObservableCollection<string> Items
    {
        get
        {
            return (ObservableCollection<string>)GetValue(ItemsProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(ItemsProperty, value);
        }
    }

public static  DependencyProperty ItemsProperty =
                DependencyProperty.Register("Items", typeof(ObservableCollection<string>), 
        typeof(MyGrid), new UIPropertyMetadata(null, OnItemsChanged));

}
```

Comment: the observablecollection should be in your viewmodel not your control...

Comment: it is already in my viewmodel. However, how do I pass it to the grid? Shouldn't the grid know how to handle the collection also?

Comment: You could define the dependency property as IEnumerable, like [ItemsControl.ItemsSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemssource.aspx) does. Or post your code so that somebody might see what's wrong with it.

Comment: I tried already with IEnumerable and didn't work also.

Comment: When you set this Items property in XAML, WPF will assign the value directly to the underlying dependency property and not call your property setter. That's perhaps why you notice that it isn't called?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would suggest not to use ObservableCollection as the type of an `Items` dependency property.

The reason for having an ObservableCollection here (I guess) is to enable the UserControl to attach a `CollectionChanged` handler when the property value is assigned. But ObservableCollection is too specific.

The approach in WPF (e.g. in [ItemsControl.ItemsSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemssource.aspx)) is to define a very basic interface type (like `IEnumerable`) and when the property is assigned a value, find out if the value collection implements certain more specific interfaces. This would at least be [INotifyCollectionChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged.aspx) here, but the collection might also implement [ICollectionView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.icollectionview.aspx) and [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx). All these interfaces wouldn't be mandatory and that would enable your dependency property to bind to all sorts of collections, starting with a plain array up to a complex [ItemCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemcollection.aspx).

Your `OnItemsChanged` property change callback would then look like this:

```
private static void OnItemsChanged(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    MyGrid grid = obj as MyGrid;

    if (grid != null)
    {
        var oldCollectionChanged = e.OldValue as INotifyCollectionChanged;
        var newCollectionChanged = e.NewValue as INotifyCollectionChanged;

        if (oldCollectionChanged != null)
        {
            oldCollectionChanged.CollectionChanged -= grid.OnItemsCollectionChanged;
        }

        if (newCollectionChanged != null)
        {
            newCollectionChanged.CollectionChanged += grid.OnItemsCollectionChanged;

            // in addition to adding a CollectionChanged handler
            // any already existing collection elements should be processed here
        }
    }
}

private void OnItemsCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    // handle collection changes here
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The WPF binding mechanism may bypass your standard CLR property and go directly to the dependency property accessors (`GetValue` and `SetValue`).

That is why logic should not be placed inside of the CLR property, but instead inside a changed handler.

Also the `ObservableCollection<string>` will never be set because when you use collection properties from XAML, like the following:

```
<local:MyGrid>
    <local:MyGrid.Items>
        <sys:String>First Item</sys:String>
        <sys:String>Second Item</sys:String>
    </local:MyGrid.Items>
</local:MyGrid>
```

It is actually calling a get on `Items` and then calling `Add` for each of the elements.