# Dependency Property Binding in UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, mvvm

My solution is implemented in MVVM. The view is a window which hosts a usercontrol. I have created a dependency property for this userControl as below :

```
public static DependencyProperty ListProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
      "ItemsList", typeof(List<RequiredClass>), typeof(UsercontrolTest));

public List<RequiredClass> ItemsList
{
    get { return (List<RequiredClass>)GetValue(ListProperty); }
    set
    {
        SetValue(ListProperty, value);
    }
}
```

This property is bound to my viewmodel property (ListOfItems) in xaml :

```
  <Window x:Class="TestProject.MainWindow"
          xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
          xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
          xmlns:Test="clr-namespace:TestProject"
          Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>             
            <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Test:UserControlTest Grid.Row="0" ItemsList="{Binding Path=ListOfItems}" /> 
        <Button Grid.Row="1" Content="AddItems" Click="Button_Click" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Also I have initialized the datacontext of the window in codebehind to the viewmodel. Problem is the binding never seems to happen and the set property is never called for the dependency property. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Those getters and setters are never called by the binding system (hence you should never place additional code there). The property is probably being set but unless you do something with it in the *declaration of the UserControl* nothing will be displayed. e.g.

```
<UserControl Name="control" ...>
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsList, ElementName=control}" />
</UserControl>
```

Comment: Bang on thats exactly what was happening. Since i cant put code in setter , any idea how can i identify if my list is changed and execute some code ?

Comment: @AabidAli: You could use an [`ObservableCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604.aspx) which fires an event on change, not sure what exactly you try to do though...

Comment: @ H.B I meant change in dependency property. Np i got it , you just need to add a Property Metadata at initialization of dp to handle propertychanged. Thanks for your help

Comment: Maybe [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9126946/dependencyproperty-getter-setter-not-being-called/9128855#9128855) is also helpful.

Comment: It worked for me, but i don't know why the datacontext from the main container is not inherited into the user control.

Comment: @FernandoUrkijoCereceda: It is inherited, and you do not want to overwrite it, so you target the control via `ElementName`.