# Object of type Data.Binding cannot be converted to type MyCustomType

Tags: c#, xaml, silverlight, binding

Probably something very simple, but can't figure out why I get this error..

`Object of type 'System.Windows.Data.Binding' cannot be converted to type 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection[IDATT.Infrastructure.Controls.Map.IMapLayerItem]'.`

I'm working on a custom control and trying to setup bindable property. Error is on XAML line below:
[image]

Code snippet from `IdattMap`

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty LayersProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Layers", typeof(List<IdattMapLayer>), typeof(IdattMap), new PropertyMetadata(null));

        public List<IdattMapLayer> Layers
        {
            get { return GetValue(LayersProperty) as List<IdattMapLayer>; }
            set { this.SetValue(LayersProperty, value); }
        }
```

Code snippet from IdattMapLayer:

```
public class IdattMapLayer
    {
        public ControlTemplate ControlTemplate { get; set; }

        public ObservableCollection<IMapLayerItem> MapItemsDataSource { get; set; }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty MapItemsDataSourceProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("MapItemsDataSource", typeof(ObservableCollection<IMapLayerItem>), typeof(IdattMap), new PropertyMetadata(OnMapItemsDataSourceChanged));


        private static void OnMapItemsDataSourceChanged(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var control = sender as IdattMap;
            if (control == null || control.MapControl == null) return;
        }
    }
```

.. And MappedData is bound to VM and it's of `ObservableCollection<IMapLayerItem>` type.

Why it expects "Binding" object and passing observable colllection does not work?

Comment: Could you please also show the declaration of the `MappedData` resource?

Comment: And please see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9128855/1136211) answer for an explanation why it might be better to use a more basic collection type.

Comment: I fixed it.. What I did I made IdattMapLayer to inherit from DependencyObject and it works now even with interface

Answer (score 0):

Bindings don't do well with Interfaces due to the use of reflection going on behind the scenes required to execute the bindings which need a certain hierarchy for it all to work.

Change your controls `MapItemsDataSource` dependency property to an observable collection with an actual instance which adheres to the interface in question.

It is unclear if this changed for the latest version of Silverlight, but someone wrote a wrapper for a dynamic binding for an interface on this thread for S4.

[Binding to an interface where the implementation class is internal. (Silverlight 3)](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/silverlight/en-US/5fd73cbc-f19b-49cd-8327-5dc3bcb77e95/binding-to-an-interface-where-the-implementation-class-is-internal-silverlight-3?forum=silverlightbugs)

Comment: OmegaMan, problem is - I can't change MapItemsDataSource to collection with hard class, need this to give some freedom to users. I tried <object> instead of interface but got same error

Comment: @katit Can you create a wrapper class which could hold the object and expose properties which are simply pass through?

Comment: I fixed it.. What I did I made IdattMapLayer to inherit from DependencyObject and it works now even with interface