# Standard way of implementing collection type property in a UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, generics, user-controls, ienumerable

When developing your own UserControl that has a collection type property, `ObservableCollection<T>` appears to be a good fit because it notifies the control about item-level changes. However, the underlying ViewModel property is of type `List<T>` and although `ObservableCollection<T>` can be constructed using a `List<T>`, I'm not sure how two-way binding will work in that scenario.

I checked out `ItemsControl.ItemSource` for reference, but it looks like MS-guys did not consider `ObservableCollection` for their purpose and instead live on the poor man's `IEnumerable`. I'm not sure how `ItemsControl` supports item-level changes since `IEnumerable` doesn't provide such notifications.

So should I use `IEnumerable`, `List<T>` or `ObservableCollection<T>` for my collection property? And how should I go about two-way binding and collection change notifications?

### Edit

My VM contains a property of type `List<Point>` named `Points` (`Point` is a complex model-level type, but for our purpose u could consider it to be X,Y coordinates). VM reads all points from the model at startup and then exposes them to the View layer through `Points` property.

My UserControl displays these points and allows user to add new points or remove existing. Since UserControls normally do not bind to VM directly and instead provide public properties that Views can then bind to the underlying VM's properties, I have added a property named `MyPoints` in the control. Upon `MouseDown` in the UserControl, I update `MyPoints` accordingly, but then need to reflect these changes in the underlying VM too.

Comment: Are you sure you need to bind back to source whenever you are using `ItemsSource`? Maybe you can enlighten us by giving examples?

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9128855/1136211) may help.

Comment: @Clemens: Very helpful indeed. Let me try it and return.

Comment: @police: a comment on why u downvoted won't be harmful.

Comment: So, can I understand this:
1. Your UserControl is not used directly as a View, but something that can be placed into part of a View?
2. You are looking into using the `ItemsControl.ItemsSource` that the View (in XAML) can directly bind to the VM? (i.e. `<MyUserControl ItemsSource="{Binding Points}" ......>`)

Comment: @Jai: Yes and yes.

Comment: @Jai: The post Clemens linked above has helped me a great deal. Unless there is a better way, I'll stick to that.

Comment: Yes, `ObservableCollection<>` is the way to go. But if you are using `System.Windows.Point`, you can also use `System.Windows.Media.PointCollection`. I tried it recently and it worked, I guess it has to do with the fact that it is derived from `DependencyObject` though. What I was doing is very similar to yours; I was making my own graph control, where VM would throw me a list of (X,Y) values that is based on the graph's value (not screen's value), and the control needs to render translate those set into screen values.

Comment: Of course, your requirement may be somewhat different, and may have different results. It's still up to you though :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally, you'd want you VM to have the `ObservableCollection` - this can tell the view every time it needs to update. Assuming you have the ability to modify the VM, I'd recommend this. If your VM does not include and `ObservableCollection`, you will not be able to receive item-level updates.

To enable two-way binding you'll need to use a dependency property in your View (only dependency properties (and specially designed classes) can accept bindings)

In your view (assuming it's called MyControl ):

```
// Provide a dependency property to enable binding
public static readonly DependencyProperty MyPointsProperty = DependencyProperty.Register( "MyPoints", typeof(ObservableCollection<Points>) ,new FrameworkPropertyMetadata( null, FrameworkPopertyMetatdataOptions.None, MyPointsPropertyChangedHandler ) );

// Provide a CLR property for convenience - this will not get called by the binding engine!
public ObservableCollection<Points> MyPoints {
    get { return (ObservableCollection<Points>) GetValue( MyPointsProperty ); } 
    set { SetValue( MyPointsProperty, value ); }
}

//Listen for changes to the dependency property (note this is a static method)
public static void MyPointsPropertyChanged( DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) {
    MyControl me = obj as MyControl;
    if( me != null ) {
        // Call a non-static method on the object whose property has changed
        me.OnMyPointsChanged( (ObservableCollection<Points>) e.OldValue, (ObservableCollection<Points>) e.NewValue );
    }
}
// ...

// Listen for changes to the property (non-static) to register CollectionChanged handlers
protected virtual void OnMyPointsChanged(ObservableCollection<Points> oldValue, ObservableCollection<Points> newValue) {
    if(oldValue!=null){
        oldValue.CollectionChanged -= MyCollectionChangedHandler;
    }
    if( newValue!=null ) {
        newValue.CollectionChanged += MyCollectionChangedHandler;
    }
}
```

With this, you can now do:

```
<ns:MyControl MyPoints="{Binding vmPointsCollection}" />
```

This code won't work as is, but should serve as a guide to implementing the necessary features you require to provide binding.

*As a side note, `ItemsControl.ItemsSource` works with `ItemsControl.Items` together to produce the overall effect, Items is an `ItemCollecton` which has a `CollectionChanged` event. When you set `ItemsSource`, `Items` is told about this, starts watching for changes in your `ItemsSource` and reports them through its `CollectionChanged` event.*

**Edit**: A better implementation of this control would have an IEnumerable as the type of the MyPoints collection and, when this is found in the handler, check if it implements INotifyCollectionChanged and attach handlers appropriately

Comment: Your Edit portion is what Clemens suggess above and that's what I ended up with. Seems pretty much the standard way of doing it. Thanks for the input. I'll accept this if no one else suggest an even better way.