# How to make a DependencyProperty on a Custom Control accept a CollectionViewSource Binding?

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, collectionviewsource

**Background:**

- I can create a `CollectionViewSource` in XAML taking data from an `ObservableCollection` on the Window.
- Binding the `CollectionViewSource` to a `DataGrid` behaves exactly as expected (`ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource ClustersView}}"`)
- Filtering of the `CollectionViewSource` works fine.
- My `CustomControl` is working fine (at least, all the other Bindings and functionality)

**Problem:**

I'm not able to (or don't know how to) create a `DependencyProperty` on my `CustomControl` that will Bind to the `CollectionViewSource` and update/trigger when the View of the ColelctionViewSource changes (ie such as when Filtering changes).

**What type should the `DependencyProperty` be so that I can bind to the `CollectionViewSource`?** `Object` type reveals the bound `CollectionViewSource` will be passed as `ListCollectionView` to my `CustomControl` `DependencyProperty` - but `ListCollectionView` doesn't provide an event (that is visible, ie. not `Internal`) for `CollectionChanged`.

Deriving `ItemsControl` as the `BaseClass` for my `CustomControl` is not an option. *A side comment - I shouldn't need to derive from `ItemsControl` to achieve this function: How would I create a `CustomControl` with 2 bindings that accept 2 different `CollectionViewSources` (`ItemsControl` would not be able to do this)?*

Code:

`CollectionViewSource` "ClustersView"

`DataGrid`: `ItemsSource` is bound to "ClustersView" (This works fine)

`NavigatorControl`: This is my `CustomControl`

**Code:**

```
<CollectionViewSource x:Key="ClustersView" 
                          Source="{Binding EventClusters, ElementName=me}" 
                          Filter="ClustersViewSource_Filter"></CollectionViewSource>

<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource ClustersView}}">

<LightMapperControls:NavigatorControl Clusters="{Binding Source={StaticResource ClustersView}}">
            </LightMapperControls:NavigatorControl>

 //The DP on NavigatorControl that I bind the CollectionViewSource to
public object Clusters
            {
                get { return (object)GetValue(ClustersProperty); }
                set { SetValue(ClustersProperty, value); }
            }
    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Clusters.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ClustersProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Clusters", typeof(object), typeof(NavigatorControl), new PropertyMetadata(null, OnClustersChanged));

private static void OnClustersChanged(DependencyObject o, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            ListCollectionView lcv = (ListCollectionView)e.NewValue;     //e.NewValue is of type ListCollectionView

            //lcv.Items     //no such property
            //lcv.CollectionChanged     //no such event
        }
```

Comment: The dependency property itself has nothing to do with the `CollectionViewSource` object. A dependency property by itself can't do anything with a collection; it just holds a reference. So: where are you actually _using_ this reference? Why doesn't the component that is using the reference already handle view changes in the view source? Please improve your question by addressing these specifics, as well as providing a good [mcve] that shows clearly what you're trying to do, what's not working, and what _specifically_ you need help with.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions @PeterDuniho. I will improve my question as best I can. To answer your questions: 1) I (want to) use the reference to trigger `OnRender` of my `CustomControl` to redraw a part of the canvas (using items in the `CollectionViewSource`). 2) 'The component' in this case is my `CustomControl`, and it does not already handle view changes in the view source.....hence my original question. Perhaps it is better written "How to make a `DependencyProperty` on a `CustomControl` 'handle' view changes in the view source"

Comment: Again, the dependency property isn't going to be involved here, unless the actual reference itself is modified (i.e. you are replacing one view source with another). Changes _in a view source_ are reported via events on the view source, and your control code should subscribe to those whenever the property value is updated, and then rerender if one of those events is raised. Knowing what you've tried, and what problem you had, would improve the chances that a good answer might be provided to your question.

Comment: You would typically declare the property as `IEnumerable` and check at runtime if the assigned object implements INotiyCollectionChanged. See e.g. here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9128855/1136211

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The solution is to let `WPF` do all the work!** I made the `Clusters` `DependencyObject` of type `object`, then added the `FrameworkPropertyMetadataOption.AffectsRender` to trigger `OnRender` to redraw the canvas whenever `Clusters` changes (ie. Filtering occurs on the CollectionViewSource). (The actual method for redrawing the canvas is `DrawClusters` called from `OnRender`). `DrawClusters` contains the cast of `Clusters` (`object`) to `ICollectionView` which I enumerate over in the `for..each` loop to access each individual `Cluster`.

Thank you @PeterDuniho for your questions that forced me to readdress what I thought I knew!

**Relevant code below**

```
    public object Clusters
    {
        get { return (object)GetValue(ClustersProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ClustersProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for MyProperty.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ClustersProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Clusters", typeof(object), typeof(NavigatorControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender));

private void DrawClusters(ref DrawingContext dc, ref double SquareWidth, ref double SquareHeight)
    {
        if (Clusters == null)
            return;
        if (ClustersVisibility == Visibility.Visible)
        {
            ICollectionView cv = (ICollectionView)Clusters;

            foreach (ClusterBase cluster in cv)
            {
                PathGeometry geometry = new PathGeometry();
                foreach (ClusterSquare square in cluster.Squares)
                {
                    geometry = Geometry.Combine(geometry, new RectangleGeometry(square.ToRect(SquareWidth, SquareHeight)), GeometryCombineMode.Union, null);
                }
                dc.DrawGeometry(clustersbrush, clusterspen, geometry);
            }
        }
    }
```